# What's the best way to store a global variable for a reusable React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React component (think a button) that makes a network request when clicked. This component may be rendered multiple times on the same page, but the network request only needs to happen once. Therefore, I want to store a variable, `networkRequestWasMade`, to check against before making the request.

Normally, I'd find a common parent and wrap it in React's context mechanism. But, this component will be part of a reusable component library that will be used across many applications (think hundreds), so I would prefer that it **doesn't rely on a specific parent component or context** to store this value. I am brainstorming about what would be the best way to achieve this.

A very simple solution would be to attach a boolean to the `window` object:

```
function Button() {

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!window.networkRequestWasMade) {
      // ...make request...
      window.networkRequestWasMade = true
    }
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</button>
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a better pattern for this.

Comment: React has [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and if it's not enough, you can use something like Redux. The downside of globals is that it leaks in the window object and React won't be able to re-render on change if ever needed.

Comment: If you don't need React to know when the flag value changes, you could isolate the flag in a module which is imported where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to not use global variables, this is a bad practice. You just need to store the promise into a variable and initialize it only the very first time.

Here is an example using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make the http call

```
// util.js
let p;

function loadData() {
  if (!p) {
    p = axios.get('uri')
      .then(response => result = response.data);
  }

  return p;
}
```

Then your component can call the function `loadData` multiple times, the http call will be executed only once

```
// Button.jsx
import { loadData } from './util'

function Button() {

  const handleClick = () => {
    loadData()
      .then(data => {
        // do what you want with the data
      })
   }

   return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</button>
}
```

Maybe the http request is not a `GET` and you don't care about the result but you get the idea.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!